# Moodle custom fields API for course page

Tags: php, plugins, customization, moodle

Unfortunately I can't quite follow how the custom field API works. What I actually want are additional fields for the custom course format such as address, directions and other (hybrid courses). And no, I don't want to use the web interface for this.

As I understand it, two files are needed, **myFormatPlugin/classes/customfields/course_handler.php**
and
**myFormatPlugin/customfield.php**

Do I need to register the customfield.php file somewhere or does it work via autoload?

Do I need to create a separate database table for this?

What am I missing?

Could someone make an example for just one field? I don't find the github links in the [documentation](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Custom_fields_API) helpful either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope you want to add some custom fields for your custom course format. To add custom fields for the format plugin you don't want to use the custom field API.

The course format plugin contains options to add your custom fields using the function `course_format_options` in your `course/format/PLUGINNAME/lib.php`.

Moodle will automatically store these custom course format options in the database table `course_format_options`.

Please have look at the designer course format plugin.

https://github.com/bdecentgmbh/moodle-format_designer/blob/master/lib.php#L241

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, works really well.
I found two more links where the [PARAM_XXX](https://github.com/moodle/moodle/blob/master/lib/moodlelib.php#L77) and [element_types](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Form_API#Form_elements) are listed.

Comment: Quick question, how do I insert the 'element_type' = > 'editor' correctly. I have it in the array $courseformatoptions like the others but the saved content from the database is not inserted into the editor in front end. 

The data is there and is saved correctly.